# CSS animation property not working/applying in react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

**EDIT:** So, for some reason, the effect did not work/apply when running it locally. But, it works fine when I deployed it to GH pages. Does anyone know why this is?

---

I have text laid out in a circle that I want to rotate about itself. On plain HTML/CSS/Javascript, it works just fine and I get the desired result. Also, when I tried it out separately on this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/stickstack/pen/yLObaRd) it works as well.
However, when I try to run this on the .rotating-circle div every style gets applied **except** for the animation. Not sure if this is relevant but I am using the [CircleType](https://circletype.labwire.ca/) js library to create this circular text.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import CircleType from 'circletype'

function RotatingCircle() { 

    const rotatingCircle = useRef(); 

    useEffect(()=> { 
        new CircleType(rotatingCircle.current).radius(100)
    }, [])

    return ( 
        <div className="rotating-circle">
           <p className="circle" id="rounded-text" ref={rotatingCircle}>
               AND THE WORLD KEEPS GOING AROUND AND AROUND AND AROUND
           </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RotatingCircle
```

Here is the SCSS:

```
.some-class{
    .rotating-circle{ 
        font-size: 1rem; 
        z-index: -999;
        font-weight: bold; 
        color:$secondary;
        display: block;
        // background: #000;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 300px;
        // border-radius: 50%;
        margin-top: -250px;
        -webkit-animation: spin1 30s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: spin1 30s infinite linear;
        -o-animation: spin1 30s infinite linear;
        -ms-animation: spin1 30s infinite linear;
        animation: spin1 30s infinite linear;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        transform-origin: 50% 80%;
    }
}
        
        @-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
            0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
            100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }
        @-moz-keyframes spin1 {
            0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
            100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }
        @-o-keyframes spin1 {
            0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
            100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }
        @-ms-keyframes spin1 {
            0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
            100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }
        @-keyframes spin1 {
            0% { transform: rotate(0deg);}
            100% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }
```

Also, just wanted to add that the .some-class class is applied to an element that this component is nested in.

Comment: Your style is wrapped in the .some-class class name which is not present in your return. Please remove .some-class {} around the .rotating-circle and try

Comment: still not working. I used SCSS and used nested selectors. I did remove the .rotating-circle class outside of it but still didn't work. All the other styles declared in .rotating-circle work (positioning, color, etc) except for the css animation style

Comment: Can you inspect the element in chrome to check whether animation has been applied

Comment: new CircleType(rotatingCircle.current[0]).radius(100)
    }, []) Also you need to change ref to this line..

Comment: It shows it has been applied--there's no strike-through through it (if that is what a strike-through indicates)

Comment: I changed the line however got a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined' error. Can you explain what that was supposed to do? Thanks